# Data not being sent to PHP from jQuery AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Following ajax code is not sending the data to PHP. Is there anything wrong with this code?

data = {"email":email,"reset_key":getUrlVars()["key"]};
console.log(data);
console.log is showing {email: "test@gmail.com", reset_key: "6d8fd92a9c49bf139f945350c7c39092"}

```
// alert($('#reset_key').val());
$.ajax({
  url: '<?=$server?>/inc/ajax.php?q=check_reset_expiry',
  data: data,
  type: 'post',
  dataType: 'json',
  processData: false,
  contentType: false,
})
.done(function(res){
  console.log(res);
  if (res.hasError) {
    $("#errMsgReset").show(100);
    $("#errMsgReset").html(res.errorMsg);
    $('#btn-reset').attr('disabled', true);
  }
})
.fail(function(err){
  console.log(err);
  $('#errMsgReset').show(100);
  $("#errMsgReset").html("Password reset failed. Please try again.");
});
```

Comment: Well what do you get on console.log(res); and  console.log(err); Also double check your url

Comment: Check the Network tab in your browser's Developer Console and check the URL the data is sent to and the data, which is sent. Then you can decide if the issue is client-side or server-side

Comment: I have sent a response back with email and key; both returning null. Nothing is logged as error.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this could help you:

```js
.done(function(data){
    console.log(data);
})
```

You get back a json string no html.
So create HTML-Code and pass it to the html() function.
Error should be in fail

```js
.fail(function(err){
    console.log(err);
});
```